# Speed of change Data network mode

Tags: android, performance

It's so slow change mode of Data network from enable to disable or disable to enable. Is there anyway to do it fast?
I use this code for change mode of Data network.
Method dataMtd;

```
    try {
        dataMtd = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
        dataMtd.setAccessible(true);
        dataMtd.invoke(mgr, true); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you want to use this , you must add these permissions :

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.gc();` to kill all of process and it can help to improve your performance for change network state.